# the population "doubled from one million"

Tags: meaning

I have a quick question. could you please tell me what exactly this sentence means?

"The population of St Petersburg *doubled from just over a million*."

Was it one million after it was doubled or was it doubled for million and became two millions?

(I know it might sound a bit funny, but I can't quite get it  out of my head and it's important.)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: From => start. So I'd read that as saying it was about a million before and went to about 2 million.

Comment: @Lawrence Yes. If it ended as on million one would say "it doubled TO a million".

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments. The population should be around 2 million now.

I think it would be more clear for you if the sentence were “The population of St. Petersburg doubled from just over a million to 2 million.”

You can think of the ‘over a million’ as the origin and the ‘2 million’ as the ‘destination’.